# log4j settings in Apache Calcite project

Tags: java, log4j, apache-calcite

I have downloaded the Apache Calcite project and opened its Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2. I had a problem that it could not load the slf4j classes correctly (I was getting the `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" error`). Finally, I resolved the problem by adding the following lines into `build.gradle.kts` of the `:core` module:

```
dependencies {
  ...   
  implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.3")
  implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.3")
  ...
}
```

Now get rid of the error; however, the logger is always set to `INFO` logging level regardless of the `core\src\test\resource\log4j.properties` setting. Currently, my `log4j.properties` looks as follows:

```
# Change rootLogger level to WARN
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, A1

# A1 goes to the console
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p - %m%n
```

I run the `CsvExample` tests and no logging occurs. When I debug, I see that the `RelOptRuleCall.LOGGER` is set to `INFO` logging level. The `RelOptRuleCall.LOGGER` is an instance of `org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger`. I was also following the https://calcite.apache.org/docs/howto.html#tracing instructions but without luck (the `RelOptRuleCall.LOGGER` is set to `INFO` despite any `log4j.properties` changes).

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2 Community edition and Windows 10. I was also trying JDK 1.8 instead of default JDK 11 but with the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. please modify the  example/csv/build.gradle.kts,

add follow lines to dependencies:

```
   testRuntimeOnly("org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12")
```

2.then copy the `core\src\test\resource\log4j.properties` to `example\src\test\resource\log4j.properties`

add follow lines:

```
# Increase level to DEBUG for RelOptPlanner
log4j.logger.org.apache.calcite.plan.RelOptPlanner=TRACE
# Increase level to TRACE for HepPlanner
log4j.logger.org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner=TRACE
```